# My moodle 3.9.19 won't open power point files, moodle site not opening on mozilla, can't upload anything from another pc to server

Tags: user-controls, powerpoint, admin, moodle

I upgraded my moodle 3.8 to 3.9.19 version. Now i have several problems... 1) power point (pptx) not opening on any pc accept my server. 2) moodle not working on mozilla firefox browser. 3) Can't upload files, videos, anything with admin account from another pc. But i can upload files in server without any problem. what to do? Pls help me

Windows Server 2012R. Mariadb 10.6.11. HeidiSQL 11.3.0.6295. PHP Version 7.4.1. Moodle 3.9.19

When i upgraded my moodle site, i installed all missing plugins. Upgraded mariadb to 10.6 version. Checked file extensions, looks everything is ok. Don't know what else to do...

Comment: Do you have any error messages for any of the 3 cases?

Comment: it is not showing any errors, thats the problem. I dont know how but right now i did upload materials from my pc.

Comment: when i click to power point file there is no any action, no errors at all.  And when user tries to enter to his account in mozilla browser, it says: your account is already running, please exit from ur account to countinue. When i exit, it quits from the site, thats all

Comment: Maybe try purging the caches, that often fixes a lot of issues -  Site administration > Development > Purge all caches - or from the command line `php admin/cli/purge_caches.php`

Comment: No, it did not help. And now i cant upload audio files. it says: An error occurred whilst communicating with the server

Comment: Oh, that might be permissions in the site data folder. Can you temporarily switch debug level to developer and check the box to display messages.  Then try again. That will tell you where the error is coming from. Then copy and paste the error message into the question and switch debug back to what it was - https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Debugging#Debug_messages

Comment: Here's some notes on changing the permissions for the data folder https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory

Comment: debugging did not help!

Comment: I found the problem. Our system admins added my site to sub domain